# Querying multiple collections orderby created time - Firebase

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get photos of the following people in newsfeed. 
I am using Google Cloud Firestore.

My db struture is:

```
Users -> userDocs -> following -> followingUserDocs
                 -> photos -> photosDocs
```

My concern is, If I follow 50 people then I need to get the posts which is posted by the 50 people sorted by created time and the limit of 10.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @AlexMamo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661462/perform-in-query-in-google-cloud-firestore

Comment: So... where's the code you've attempted? We would need to take a look at that to see what the issue is. Probably need to get a better description of your Firebase structure as well. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)