# Making a query to multiple collection in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections where one collection is referencing another. Below is my structure:

`CURRENCY_PAIR`

1. CurrencyPair_Name
2. CurrencyPair_id

`CURRENCY_PAIR_LIMIT`

1. Limit_Currency_Pair_Id  :         *CURRENCY_PAIR/0chTWgOpzolSxj590N1U*   <=makes a reference to the document in the CURRENCY_PAIR collection
2. Limit_Buy_Price_Threshhold

How can i query both collections such that when i get a currency pair, it is equal to the `Limit_Buy_Price_Threshhold` field that was added to the db with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56666799/7031308), Firestore does not have a concept of server-side JOIN which is very near to what you want to achieve when you mentioned that you wanted to query both collections.

What I could think of is that you could remodel your database in a way that you can perform [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). It works by putting `CURRENCY_PAIR_LIMIT` as a subcollection to the document in `CURRENCY_PAIR`.